# Conversion of a list to a dictionary python

Tags: json, list, python-2.7, dictionary, box

```
{
    "event_type": "ITEM_PREVIEW", 
    "event_id": "67521d60cbb5f4dedef901d5e82f394ed122662d", 
    "created_at": "2015-10-21T14:12:46-07:00"
}
```

I have this json which is being read as a list; how do I

1. convert it to a json

or

2. convert it to a dict such as *event_type* = *key* and *ITEM_PREVIEW* = *value*

I tried converting in to a string and use `json.Encoder`
I also tried this the first function gets events and saves it to a file the I want the second one to be able to parse the information

```
def events():
    for event in client.events().generate_events_with_long_polling():
        print(event)
        ev = open('events.txt', 'a')
        json.dump(event, ev)
        ev.write('\n')
    ev.close()
    return ev
#events()



def trigger():
    entries = open('events.txt', 'rU')
    print('\n', type(entries))
    dictss = entries.readlines()
    print('\n', type(dictss), '\n', len(dictss))
    for q in dictss:
        print(q)
        w = dict([x.strip().split(":") for x in dictss if " " in x])
    print(w)


trigger()
```

Comment: "I have this json which is being read as a list" Certainly not the JSON you show there; that would be parsed as a dict.

Comment: is there a way to make it a json or a dict so i can set a trigger